# angularjs - Error: [$rootScope:infdig]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I recently updated my controller and factories to get a better scope of handling my data flow, my Controller looks like this:

```
uno.controller('newsCtrl', function($scope, $http, adbFactory, $cacheFactory, unoFunctions){
    $scope.init = function(){
        adbFactory.get($http, 'get all blog_posts', true).success(function(data){
            $scope.posts = data;

            $scope.getUser = function(_id) {
            $scope.userData = unoFunctions.getUser(_id);
                //console.log($scope.userData);

                return $scope.userData;
            };
        });

        $scope.getTags = function(_id) {
            var post = unoFunctions.getPost(_id);
            var _tags = post.tags.split(',');
            for(var i = 0; i < _tags.length; i++)
            {
                _tags[i] = _tags[i].trim();
            }

            return _tags;
        };

        $scope.getUserName = function(_id) {
            $scope.userData = unoFunctions.getUser(_id);
            return $scope.userData.display_name;
        };

        $scope.getUser = function(_id) {
            $scope.userData = unoFunctions.getUser(_id);
            //console.log($scope.userData);
            return $scope.userData;
        };

        $scope.getUserName = function(_id) {
            $scope.userData = unoFunctions.getUser(_id);
            return $scope.userData.display_name;
        };
    };
});
```

the unoFunctions factory is wht I use now to handle certain requests from my database, and that is shown below.

```
uno.factory('unoFunctions', function(adbFactory, $http, $cacheFactory){
    var fact = {};

    var user = $cacheFactory('user');
    var post = $cacheFactory('post');

    fact.getUser = function(_id) {
        if(!user.get(_id)){
            adbFactory.get($http, 'get users id '+_id+' spec', false).success(function(data){
                user.put(_id, data);
            });
        }

        return user.get(_id);
    };
    fact.getPost = function(_id) {
        if(!post.get(_id))
        {
            adbFactory.get($http, 'get blog_posts id '+_id+' spec', false).success(function(data){
                post.put(_id, data);
            });
        }

        return post.get(_id);
    };

    fact.loggedIn = function()
    {
        console.log('gfdg');
    };

    /*------------------------------*/
    return fact;
});
```

And my template to output the result is this:

```
<div class="large-12 small-12 columns" ng-init="init()">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 small-12 columns" ng-repeat="topic in posts | filter:postTitle | orderBy:'-time' " style="margin-bottom:20px;">
            <div id="news-post" class="panel animated fadeInUp" ng-init="getTags(topic.id)">
                <div class="row" style="padding-bottom:0px;">
                    <div class="large-2 small-2 columns">
                        <img src="{{ topic['thumb'] }}" alt="" style="border-radius:50%; height:120px; width: 200px;" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="left large-10 small-10 columns">
                        <div class="row" style="padding-bottom:0px;">
                            <h2 class="post-title">
                            <a href="#/news/post/{{ topic['id'] }}">
                            {{topic['title']}} 
                            </a> 
                            <p style="font-size:13px; font-style:italic; color:#a5a5a5" class="right">{{ topic.time | timeago }} {{  }}</p>
                            <p style="font-weight:bold; font-style:italic; color:#aaa">Posted By, {{ getUser(topic.author_id).display_name }}</p></h2>
                            <p>{{ topic['body'] }}</p> 
                            <div ng-repeat="tag in getTags(topic.id)"><span style="background:#ccc; margin:7px; padding:4px; border-radius:5px; font-size:12px" class="left">{{ tag }}</span></div>
                            <p class="right" style="background:#dedede; font-size:13px; padding:7px; border-radius:6px; color:#1985A1;">{{ topic.category }}</p
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works fine and returns the required results I'm looking for but I wish to get rid of the countless Error: `[$rootScope:infdig]` errors and keep my console clean.. I researched the error and it seems to be because when I call functions from the unoFunctions factory like, getUser, or getPost. it returns a new array each time or something like that which I guess throws things out of scope. I'm not entirely sure, but is there a solution to this?

Comment: did you read about it in angular [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig]) ?

Comment: Yes, but im still lost